# How to read Shopping Cart data from the Home page

Tags: javascript, jquery

My question is, how do you access the contents of a shopping cart via javascript when you're on the home page and **not** on the shopping cart page?

For example - https://www.vitamix.com/us/en_us/

Add an item to your shopping cart from vitamix.

Then navigate to the home page.

From here, how would you access what is in your shopping cart? I would think it would be localStorage but I'm not sure. I imagine it would work the same across any other site that uses a shopping cart.

I'm basically asking...how can you get and parse the cart page HTML from the home page?

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Your cart is probably stored inside your database and connection is some session id. You do not need script, but to tweak your CMS and output cart content (hint: look how it was done on the Cart page).

Answer (score -1):

I think maybe ajax is more helpful, but localStorage also can meet your requirements

Comment: Your answer is not helping.

Comment: when you back to hoempage, add a query string in your url.  https://www.vitamix.com/us/en_us/?cart=